# Formal letter: what is the English version of "En attandant votre réponse, veillez croire, Monsieur, à l’expression de ..."

Tags: translation, formality, formal-language

I have a hard time writing a formal letter in English for the first time in my life and without any good reference or previous training. I am stuck in the final phase where I want to express that I am waiting with hope for a favorable respose and by then I want the receiver to accept my salutations.

In French, I would write something like:

> "Dans l'attente d'une réponse de votre part, je vous prie de croire, Madame, Monsieur, à l’expression de mes salutations les plus distinguées."

Moreover, are such expressions acceptable in English formal letters?

Comment: This sort of diction vanished from all but the stuffiest letters a century ago; if you employed it today you would be suspected of irony, if not downright mockery. We would say something along the lines of *I look forward to your response. /Sincerely yours, / Aymane Fihadi*

Comment: @StoneyB :) It is strange, in French omitting them is what will be considered abnormal.

Comment: The French enjoy demonstrating their mastery of these formulas. The English and Americans enjoy demonstrating their indifference to them. It's a matter of taste.

Comment: Actually, if you pray the receiver of your missive to believe in the expression of your most distinguished salutations, they may wonder if the postal services messed up and only now delivered a letter from the Victorian era!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I look forward to your reply.
>   I look forward to hearing back from you.
>   I look forward to hearing your answer.

would all be acceptable.  AmE and BrE are not as formal as your example.